# How to handle ZeroDivisionError inside numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two big numpy arrays, I need to divide them.

Since I am working on Python 32-bits, and the arrays are too big, to avoid `FloatingPointError`, I am doing, for example:

```
x = numpy.array([...],dtype=object)
y = numpy.array([...].dtype=object)
```

The problem is that, inside the array `y`, some elements can be 0.0

So, my question, how to handle the calculation `x/y` and avoid `ZeroDivisionError`.

For exmaple, I would like to force `nan` if the element in `y` is 0. So that, for that particular element inside the array, the calculation `x/y=nan`

Comment: Could you just replace `0.0` to `1`

Comment: No, this will produce `x/y = x`, I do not want that.

Comment: It depends on why you're doing the division. For instance, you could replace elements which are zero with a sufficiently small quantity so the end result of the division is still acceptable for further use. Another possibility is conceptualising what does `x/0` mean in your use case, and handling it in your code accordingly.

Comment: `y[y == 0] = np.nan` will set all zeros in `y` to `nan`. However in numpy division through zero only raises a warning and will produce `±inf` which you can then turn to a very large number by using `np.nan_to_num`... the correct approach depends on your usecase.

Comment: Thanks swenzel, this might work

Comment: How exactly does a `dtype=object` help with very large arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use masked arrays,

```
x = numpy.array([...],dtype=object)
y = numpy.array([...].dtype=object)

x_m = numpy.ma.array(x, mask=(x==0))
y_m = numpy.ma.array(y, mask=(y==0))

print(x_m/y_m)
```

Comment: The mask is inverted compared to what it should be and this does not work for object arrays anyway (at least as of numpy 1.15)

Comment: @GaëtandeMenten Fixed the inverted mask, thanks. Just double checked -- `np.ma.array(..., dtype=object)` works with numpy 1.15, not sure why you say it doesn't.

Comment: Indeed, but then x_m/y_m throws a TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 1):

Change `dtype = object` by `dtype = float` so division by zero will not throw runtime error but it will be considered as `inf` and than change `inf` by zeros.

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='float')
b = np.array([0,1,3], dtype='float')
c = a / b
c
array([ inf,   2.,   1.])
c[c == np.inf] = 0
c
array([ 0.,  2.,  1.])
```